# Springboot application, deploy in Render fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, deployment

i'm experiencing an issue with my java app, i'm trying to deploy it on render, in a docker container.

my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
MAINTAINER SchJavier
COPY /out/artifacts/agilstratApi_jar agilstratApi.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "agilstratApi.jar"
```

the deploy logs throw me this error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile agilstratApi.jar
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Something curious that may have something to do with it, when I upload the changes to the remote repository, it gives me this warning:

```
warning: File out/artifacts/agilstratApi_jar/agilstratApi.jar is 50.22 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

I was reading the github docs and the warning shouldn't be a problem, but I don't really know.

I tried to modify the jdk in the docker file, also tried rebuilding the .jar file and update the github repo, but nothing results well.

I have searched up in google and found no answer, any idea or tip to solve ir?

[update]

I ran .jar locally, and didn't work, so that's was why Render cannot run the app. Now i got a lot of new issues to share with you!

Well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to Render documentation you can either deploy a Docker image or build the jar on Render and deploy it. Deploying a jar made locally and uploaded to GitHub is not described. Probably it is not supported.

The following Dockerfile works for me:

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /target/rest-api-template-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rest-api-template.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=render","-jar","rest-api-template.jar"]
```

Comment: I ran .jar file localy and doensn't work, that's why Render cannot run the app.

Comment: here are the new issues -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78096301/openapi-specification-works-on-jvm-but-not-on-jar-file